# How to pull multiple column values into a single column in Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having 12 columns which are getting auto filled up by the formula "IMPORTRANGE".

I need to collate all the table values to a single value (condition is it should behave like as "ARRAYFORMULA").

Just wondering is there any specific formula/query exist for this purpose.

I have added the sample snapshot of my sheet. I need these RED highlighted values in a different column, let's say at "EF".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### **Common case**

I'll show sample formula for 3 columns, but you may use the same logic for any number of columns.

[image]

the formula is

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:C,A2:A>0)&"-"))),"-"))
```

- `A2:C` is the range with all your columns
- `A2:A>0` is the condition by column A to choose only proper rows. This may by `A2:A<>""` for text column or any condition to limit number of rows.
- `-` in the formula is any symbol which is not the part of original data. You may use group of symbols, or even special words for the same purpose: `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:C,A2:A>0)&"devide"))), "devide"))`

---

### **Case 1.**

**not continuous columns**

If you have data are **not in continuous** columns.

If so, then you need to change this part of formula `FILTER(A2:C,A2:A>0)` into query:

`=query(A:AO;"select A,I,Q,Y,AG,AO... where A > 0")`

or better this:

`=query({A:AO};"select Col1, Col6, Col20, Col22, ... where Col1 > 0")`

And the final formula will look like this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(query({A:AO};"select Col1, Col6, Col20, Col22, ... where Col1 > 0")&"-"))),"-"))
```

---

### **Case 2.**

**not continuous columns, data is numbers and text**

When you have both numbers and text as input into your data, `query` won't work because it can handle only one type of data in one column.

Your simplified case will look like this:

[image]

The first task is to grab all columns with the name "Ticket number" into one table.

Let's work in the sheet "Report", use `filter` function:

```
=FILTER(Data!1:1001,Data!2:2="Ticket number")
```

and get the result:

[image]

Step 2 is implementing the first formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(Report!A3:D&"-"))),"-"))
```

---

The other way is to combine columns one by one:

```
={A2:A5;B2:B5;C2:C5}
```

If you like this method, you may [read more here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).

Comment: That's pretty clever! I never knew this could be done so concisely natively.

Comment: Hi Max, Thank you for a quick response. But my data are not in continuous columns. My data are in (A,I,Q,Y,AG,AO....DY) these columns. And I need to collate these data in my "EF" column.

Comment: You can simply construct that range then with the seconds approach he mentioned, just use `,` instead of `;` to bind the columns.

Comment: I've proposed using query instead of filter in this case. The query is good for the reason, because you may build the SQL text to search column numbers in the data. It's a bit harder and is off-topic to the question, but gives you more power and control of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ya Max, I have implemented the Query which is running fine.Thanks a lot for your great response.

Comment: Jyotiranjan, this error means wrong query sintax, to solve it: try deleting parts of query and defining, which of them is wrong. To say more, I need sample of data with the error.

Comment: Hi Max, Please look at my edited question. I have added a sample snapshot. I need to collate the red highlighted ticket numbers into a separate column. Please help me here. Thank you.

Comment: You have numbers and text in your data, This is not the option for use of `query`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Max. One of my big issue resolved.. Once again Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Max's answer is very good and I'd recommend using that if it solves your problem.

In case you want a bit more flexibility though, I have written a library called [Reshape](https://github.com/RobinGertenbach/Reshape) that allows you to melt data in a long format like you desire.
You could run something like:

```
=MELT(IMPORTRANGE(<spreadsheet>, "A:DY"), , , , 1)
```

It puts column headers tinto their own column to make identification clear which may or may not be what you want (since you only talk about putting values into one columns which is what this script does). Take a look at the two tables in the link to see what the function conceptually does and see if it's right for you.

I don't have it published as an add-on outside of my network so you'd need to copy and paste the code into your script

Comment: Thak you Robin. I followed the query mentioned by Max. It worked. Thanks a lot.